How would submission deadlines be applied to elections following a failed Vertrauensfrage?
Germany has a unique way of dissolving parliament. If the chancellor loses a vote of confidence, the president can dissolve the Bundestag within 21 days, which would lead to elections within 60 days.
Given that the Bundespräsident could dissolve the Bundestag immediately after the vote of confidence has been lost, you could theoretically have new elections less than 60 days later.
However, elections have deadlines. §19 BWahlG specifies that candidates for constituencies and candidate lists for the states have to be submitted by 6 pm on the 69th day before the election.
If a non-established party wants to run in the election they have to declare that by the 97th day before the election, which would be an impossible deadline even if the president took the maximum amount of time.
How do people run in these elections, given the fact that it may be impossible to declare your candidacy after it is announced that the election is even happening?

I'm happy that I'm not the only who is aware of what is going on in germany. Upvoted.

TL;DR: §52(3)

(3) Das Bundesministerium des Innern und für Heimat wird ermächtigt, im Falle einer Auflösung des Deutschen Bundestages die in dem Bundeswahlgesetz und in der Bundeswahlordnung bestimmten Fristen und Termine durch Rechtsverordnung ohne Zustimmung des Bundesrates abzukürzen.

So the ministry of the interior is allowed to shorten the deadlines in case of an unscheduled new election without the approval of the governments of the federal states (Bundesrat).
Here is for example how that looked like in case of the 2005 election:
https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/535006/5c4e8b62072752bed322b3e0bf61fc0c/WD-3-192-17-pdf.pdf
But apparently this norm was overruled in 2016 so there needs to be a new one.

 Also no, the president can not immediately dissolve the Bundestag (German parliament).
Dissolving parliament is a tricky issue, especially given it's frequent abuse in the declining Weimar Republic, where "Presidential cabinets" ruled for much of the later period, where the president dissolved parliament and appointed a lame duck government which ruled largely by laws crafted via executive orders of the president, while the parliament was absent. So the rights of the president to dissolve parliament have been majorly restricted and deadlines are set to keep that vacancy period short.
Apparently this is set in articles 63, 67 and 68 of the constitution.
Essentially 63 (german) allows for dissolution of parliament if no chancellor is elected in the first place. So usually the president proposes the most likely chancellor, biggest faction, leader of a coalitions, etc then a vote is held, if that votes fails parliament itself can propose a candidate and if that one fails as well to achieve a majority of MPs as well, then the president can dissolve and schedule new elections.
Article 67 (german) allows for parliament itself to rid itself of a chancellor, how such a vote of no confidence MUST be concurrent with the election of a new chancellor (who would need to get the majority). So parliament can no dissolve itself.
Unless (article 68 (german) the chancellor poses a vote of confidence where he aims to get the approval of a majority of parliament (usually the members of his own coalition suffice for that) and if that vote of confidence is lost the president can dissolve parliament within 21 days unless the other parties jump in an elect a new chancellor with a majority.
So as a chancellor was elected by a majority article 63 no longer applies. Meaning either the rest of parliament needs to form a new majority coalition (which is unlikely). So the current government can stay in office unless they themselves create a vote of confidence in order to make space for new elections. And apparently the government has scheduled that question to be raised on the 15th of January 2025. So in terms of practical problems the other parties have time to prepare for that in advance while the official dead lines are likely to be placed within the constraints of the 60 days via a norm issued by the government.
Edit: Also while the president dissolving parliament doesn't shorten the 60 days, the 60 days still are an upper limit so they could do it faster if they wanted to. Though there could also be limits with regards to how fast exactly, for example the time between a proposing a vote of no confidence and having the vote is for 2 days or explicitly 48 hours actually. 

That makes sense, I should have just read the BWahlG further.

I also edited my answer to specify that I meant the president could dissolve the Bundestag immediately after the vote of confidence has been lost.
